# Android set image from file

Tags: java, android

I have a question file. I am reading it and I want set image to ImageView from file. For ex:

```
img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.+"simdikiSoru.getUlkeAdi()");
```

but it isn't working.

Comment: Image is inside `mipmap` folder or located  on file system ?

Comment: images are in mipmap folder

Answer (score 1):

`R.mipmap` will refer to resources, not files on the device's filesystem.

The best solution is to use one of the [many image-loading libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

```
Picasso.with(this).load(...).into(img);
```

where `this` is your `Activity` and `...` is a `File` or `Uri` pointing to your image.

If you do not wish to use a library, then you can create your own subclass of `AsyncTask`, use `BitmapFactory` to load in a `Bitmap` in the task's `doInBackground()` method, and then set the `Bitmap` on the `ImageView` in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Not confirm, can we use `getIdentifier ` to set image if image is in mipmap in Android Studio

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: Yes, but that is still a resource, not a file on the device's filesystem. I am interpreting the question as referring to a file on the filesystem.

Comment: I am doing a quiz program and I want change image in every question.

Answer (score 0):

The images your put into res/drawable are handled by Android. The best way to call upon an image in the folder would be

setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_name)